# How to check how many scenes are in a build in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a mobile game with many scenes (AKA Levels) in Unity, I also intend on adding more levels through updates later in the games life cycle. To cope with this I am attempting the make an automated script that see's how many scenes there are in the Unity build, and create corresponding UI buttons based on a prefab.

For clarity sake I'll note that when I say "scenes that are in ther Unity Build", I mean scenes that are in the build menu:

[image]

And already have an index number.

It's not a lot but here is my current script which I have a levelManager in the scene:

```
    private Scene[] levels;

    private void Start()
    {
        /// This is the line I'm requesting help with
        levels = // Some way of getting all the scene's in a project put in an array


        foreach (var item in levels)
        {
            // I will handle the button creation and modification later that will go here
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said you don't create that variable yourself but rather can simply read out [`SceneManager.sceneCountInBildSettings`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneCountInBuildSettings.html) and then use [`SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex.html) in order to iterate and get all these scenes like

```
// Adjust this in the Inspector
// Set this to the index of level 1
[SerializeField] private int startIndex = 1;

var sceneCount = SceneManager.sceneCountInBildSettings;
levels = new Scene[sceneCount - startIndex];
for(var i = startIndex; i < sceneCount; i++)
{
    level[i] = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(i);
}
```

---

Alternatively you could also do it already before runtime via an editor script using [`EditorBuildSettings.scenes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorBuildSettings-scenes.html) e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

...

// Make this field serialized so it gets stored together with the scene
[SerializeField] private Scene[] levels;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [ContextMenu(nameof(StoreScenes))]
    private void StoreScenes()
    {
        levels = EditorBuildSettings.scenes;
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);    
        EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
    }
#endif
```

you would run this method before the build by going to the Inspector of your component, open the context menu and hit `StoreScenes` and it will fill your array. The `#if UNITY_EDITOR` has to wrap anything using the `UnityEditor` namespace as it will be stripped of in a build and you would get build exceptions otherwise.

Comment: @JhonPiper that's true .. typing this on my phone so ;) should be working now

Comment: That works now, one more question before I mark your answer as correct. Say I had a main menu and I wanted to skip the first or first couple of id's in the build settings, is there a way to do that with this setup?

Comment: Just let the for loop start at the index of level1 AMD reduce the array size accordingly e.g. `levels = new Scene[sceneCount - 3]; for(var i = 3; ...`